# Unable to save object to localStorage

Tags: reactjs, next.js, async-await, local-storage

I'm trying to set an object to localStorage. I'm able to set localStorage but the object value stays null. I think it has to do with the way i'm using async / await.

I know that i'm setting the state correctly because when i log the user in and push to the index page it shows the object.

I'm using `{JSON.stringify(userObj)}` to show the state on the homepage and it shows up.

I'm riddled as to why it's not setting to localStorage though.

```
const submitHandler = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password,
      }),
    };

    await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/login", requestOptions).then(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        response.json().then((data) => {
          setUserObj({
            user: data.user,
            token: data.token,
          });
        });
      }
    );

    localStorage.setItem("auth-new", JSON.stringify(userObj));

    setUser({ email: "", password: "" });
    router.push("/");
  };
```

[image]

Comment: *"I'm riddled as to why it's not setting to localStorage though"* `userObj` is a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) over the current *(const)* value in that state. It will never change inside that function; not untill the next render when a new `submitHandler` function is generated with a closure over the new, updated `userObj`.

Comment: And avoid mixing `await` and `then()`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I guess i was mixing a promise and async await?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating react state is asynchronous, you cannot immediately access it after setting a value. This is the reason why you see null in local storage.

You can solve the issue by moving the localStorage.setItem in the then block like this. (By the way since you are using then, there is no need to use await)

```
     fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/login", requestOptions).then(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        response.json().then((data) => {
          const userData = {
            user: data.user,
            token: data.token,
          }
          setUserObj(userData);
          localStorage.setItem("auth-new", JSON.stringify(userData));
        });
      }
    );
```

Or if you want to use async await:

```
 const submitHandler = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password,
      }),
    };

    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/login", requestOptions);

    if (!response.ok) {
      const message = `An error has occured: ${response.status}`;
      throw new Error(message);
    }

    const data = await response.json();

    const userData = {
      user: data.user,
      token: data.token,
    };

    setUserObj(userData);

    localStorage.setItem("auth-new", JSON.stringify(userData));

    setUser({ email: "", password: "" });
    router.push("/");
  };
```